# Is anyone developing facebook apps on Grails

Tags: facebook, grails

I have not seen much support for Grails to develop facebook apps.I was just wondering if people around are developing facebook apps on grails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jozef Dransfield: 
http://www.grassr.com/wordpress/?cat=8

Answer (score 4):

I'm deep into Facebook integration from the social networking site ESMZone.com. I originally started using the Grails [facebook-connect plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/facebook-connect) and had good success at Facebook sign-on integration with the Grails jScurity plugin. However, as I attempted to implement other features, particularly Friend Invitations, I found that the facebook-connect plugin uses an old facebook SDK that was not compatible with the newer Javascript SDK. Documentation and examples using this newer SDK were readily available in searches unlike for the older API.

I switched to the Grails [facebook-graph plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/facebook-graph) and was able to work seemlessly with the Javascript API and get friend invitation working.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked last weeks on a use-case concerning only server-side integration (no facebook connect style application). See some of my thoughts here : http://lbroudoux.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/integrating-facebook-from-a-grails-app/. Solution is actually implemented on Trailplans.com application.

Answer (score 0):

I helped out a startup in San Francisco that are using Grails with facebook apps.
So yes, it's happening. There is even a grails plugin for facebook integration (at the time I'm writing this is woefully incomplete, but looks like it's having work done so check up on it again soon).